# Does The ClientToScreen() Function Not Handle Signed Client Coordinates?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

To achieve drag-and-drop functionality, when I receive a button-down message, I capture the cursor and detect the coordinates when I receive a button-up message. To detect the window class the cursor is over when I receive a button-up message, I first convert from client coordinates to screen coordinates with ClientToScreen(), obtain the window handle with WindowFromPoint(), and then obtain the class name with GetClassName().

The issue is when the cursor is to the left or above the client area. The client coordinates are negative values as noted in the ClientToScreen() [remarks section of API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-clienttoscreen#remarks). However, when ClientToScreen() is called, the client coordinates aren't treated as signed values and the resulting coordinates aren't the expected values.

I find it strange that the documentation would note to expect negative client coordinates, and then the function fail to handle them. Is the typical work-around to call ClientToScreen() on the client area origin and subtract the difference from the result?

Comment: It handles signed coordinates fine. (Even if it treated them as unsigned coordinates, the results would still be correct thanks to the magic of two's complement math.) My guess is that your program is not DPI-aware.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a casting issue. The lParam of the WM_LBUTTONUP message gives the x & y-coordinates as a signed SHORT (16-bits). Since these are signed values, one cannot simply set them equal to the x & y coordinates of a POINT structure. ClientToScreen() works on a POINT structure, which stores each coordinate as a LONG (32-bits), thus making the two's complement SHORT value incorrect.

Thank you @RaymondChen for pointing me in the right direction, and for everything else you do in and outside of this forum.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Truncating a signed 32-bit value to a signed 16-bit value will yield the same (negative) value, so long as the value fits in 16 bits. Whatever is wrong, this is not an explanation. Maybe start by adding a [mcve] to the question?

Comment: @IInspectable I think the problem was that the values were treated as unsigned 16-bit values, so they were zero extended instead of sign extended.

Comment: Use `GET_X_LPARAM` and `GET_Y_LPARAM`, see  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttondown